# Google Places API: How to go from address to "good" place_id?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

On the google places api site, they have an example query that returns a load of detail:

site:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

query:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=My-API-Key

Place_id appears to be the key here. So I'm trying to reverse-engineer this example, starting from information that a human being would actually have, to end up with this place_id.

Address from the example:
48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont NSW 2009, Australia

Places API query from the address:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=48+Pirrama+Rd,+Pyrmont+NSW+2009,+Australia&key=My_API_Key

The result contains a different place_id:
ChIJ8UadyjeuEmsRDt5QbiDg720

And the place details with that place_id are much poorer than the original example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ8UadyjeuEmsRDt5QbiDg720&key=My-API-Key

So what am I missing here? How do I start from human-place information and get to the place_id that has the great place details?

EDIT: why the down votes? Am I trying to do something that isn't allowed?

Thanks,
sff

Answer (score 0):

I think your text search is returning [the office building](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/48+Pirrama+Rd,+Pyrmont+NSW+2009,+Australia/@-33.8666463,151.1936603,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x6b12ae37ca9d46f1:0x6defe0206e50de0e!8m2!3d-33.8666463!4d151.1958543), whereas your first search is returning the [Google office within the office building](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Google/@-33.8666199,151.1936587,17z/data=!3m2!4b1!5s0x6b12ae378e9a7ac7:0x881f184497026074!4m5!3m4!1s0x6b12ae37b47f5b37:0x8eaddfcd1b32ca52!8m2!3d-33.8666199!4d151.1958527). You can fix your text search by [adding the name of the company and removing some of the search terms](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Google%2048%20Pirrama%20Rd,%20Pyrmont&key=myAPIkey).

I'm not sure why just adding 'google' to the search term doesn't return the result you want though.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)